# Parse query to retrieve all rows, android

Tags: android, database, parse-platform

i have this simple method in DatabaseHelper class i made.
this method gives me back all rows of ParseObjects from table "Users".
the variable "list" is defined as an attribute of the class with null, and in the method "done" i put there the "users" (the list i get from the Parse).
then i return "list".
The problem i face with is that method "done" is skipped. the code while running does not enter the method "done". and it always return me "list" as it was defined  - null.

```
  public List<ParseObject> getAllData() {
    ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = new ParseQuery<ParseObject>("Users");
    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
        @Override
        public void done(List<ParseObject> users,ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {
                list = users;
            }
        }
    }); return list;
}
```

Comment: So you set a breakpoint there and it doesn't hit it?  If so, did it hit a breakpoint before calling the query?

Comment: i did not set a breakpoint.... idk whats the problem it supposed to work.

Comment: Then how do you know done is not being called? I suggest stepping through with a debugger to understand what is happening. Most likely you're getting an exception, which the code you've shown ignores. This is a bad practice and you should get in the habit of handling exceptions.

Comment: I used debugger. i see the code just skips "done". maybe i get exception. but why? its so simple becuase i have my custom table. i succses insert information to the table, so the connetcion beween the code to the Parse is good. now i just ask to retreive it. thx for helping btw...

Comment: How about `else { Log.e("tag","oops",e); }` and then you'll know?  Sounds like right now you're just guessing at what's happening.